# Select records in MySQL satisfying custom filters from other table as 1-n relation

Tags: mysql

Given the table `subscriptions` with the following structure

```
----------------------------------------
| id | userId | name | recipient   | … |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 500    | Foo  | foo@abc.com | … |
| 2  | 3244   | Bar  | bar@abc.com | … |
| 3  | 543654 | Blah | blah@abc.de | … |
----------------------------------------
```

And the table `subscription_filters` with the following structure

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | subscriptionId | type     | value     |
----------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1              | category | it        |
| 2  | 1              | category | design    |
| 3  | 1              | type     | full-time |
| 4  | 1              | type     | part-time |
| 5  | 2              | type     | full-time |
| 6  | 3              | type     | full-time |
----------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is get all `subscription` recordsets for which a filter with the given type is either not set, or has the value I need. For example:

Query with `category: it` and `type: full-time` should give me all 3 subscriptions.

Query with `category: construction` and `type: full-time` should give me subscriptions `2` and `3` because `1` has a `category` filter which does not include `construction`.

Query with `type: part-time` should give me only subscription `1` because the others all have `full-time`.

Is it possible to do this with one query efficiently?

Comment: Please correct your question. There are many errors.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: example, there is no `construction` in your data. In your queries, you are having conditions with `and`, but the result you expect is of  `or` .

Comment: Yes, there is no `construction` in my data and that is the point. Subscriptions `2` and `3` don't have *any* category filter at all so querying for `construction` or `foobar` will not filter them out.

Comment: The filter table should be used to reduce the number or results I get. If I query with a filter type that is not set for a subscription, then that filter has no effect for the given subscription. If the filter type is set, then the value I query needs to be set in the table.

Comment: To make this clearer, I am building a service that lets people subscribe to job offers posted on a site. They can fine-tune the subscription to include only job offers from certain categories, that have certain working hours, etc. If I don't set any filter, I get all job offers. If I set the category filter to "it", I get all job offers related to the category "it". If I set the category filter to "it" and the working hours to "full-time" and "part-time", get job offers related to "it" which are for full-time or part-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It checks for a match on "category" (`sf1.value = @category`), or that there was no entry of type `category` (`sf1.id IS NULL`) or that "category" was not specified (`@category = ''`), and likewise for "type". To demonstrate the query, I have used MySQL variables as placeholders, you would substitute the appropriate values when you build the query.

```
SET @category = 'it';
SET @type = 'full-time';
SELECT s.*, sf1.value AS category, sf2.value AS type
FROM subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN subscription_filters sf1 ON sf1.subscriptionID = s.id AND sf1.type = 'category'
LEFT JOIN subscription_filters sf2 ON sf2.subscriptionID = s.id AND sf2.type = 'type'
WHERE (sf1.id IS NULL OR sf1.value = @category OR @category = '') AND
      (sf2.id IS NULL OR sf2.value = @type OR @type = '');
```

Output:

```
id  userId  name    recipient       category    type    
1   500     Foo     foo@abc.com     it          full-time
2   3244    Bar     bar@abc.com     NULL        full-time
3   543654  Blah    blah@abc.de     NULL        full-time
```

You can run your other queries by setting the values of @category and @type appropriately. Where you don't want to use a filter type, set it to `''` e.g.

```
SET @category = '';
SET @type = 'part-time';
SELECT s.*, sf1.value AS category, sf2.value AS type
FROM subscriptions s
LEFT JOIN subscription_filters sf1 ON sf1.subscriptionID = s.id AND sf1.type = 'category'
LEFT JOIN subscription_filters sf2 ON sf2.subscriptionID = s.id AND sf2.type = 'type'
WHERE (sf1.id IS NULL OR sf1.value = @category OR @category = '') AND
      (sf2.id IS NULL OR sf2.value = @type OR @type = '');
```

Output:

```
id  userId  name    recipient       category    type    
1   500     Foo     foo@abc.com     it          part-time
1   500     Foo     foo@abc.com     design      part-time
```

[Demo on Rextester](http://rextester.com/VXDWQV18374)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope it helps. The below query gives the result for

> Query with category: it and type: full-time should give me all 3
>   subscriptions

```
SELECT * FROM subscriptions 
WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT subscriptionId FROM subscription_filters
WHERE ((type = 'category' AND value = 'it') 
OR (type = 'type' AND value = 'full-time'))
);
```

You would have to just change the conditions `AND / OR` and the values for `type and value`.

Comment: But if a subscription has no filter at all, this query won't include that subscription, which is wrong. It also doesn't satisify the other two conditions from my Question.

Comment: We would have to make the query generation dynamic using programming language. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I already have a solution for doing the filtering in PHP. I was hoping to be able to do the filtering in MySQL directly, but I assume this would require many joins for each filter type and value.

Comment: True smares. You can use PHP for filtering. Another approach is to create string variables with possible combination of conditions and then use them to create mysql queries dynamically.